# OSX Yosemite - JVM Shared library does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-yosemite-beta

Downloaded OS X Yosemite Beta 3 and I'm trying to run some eclipse based IDE's, namely Titanium Studio and Aptana Studio.

Running into this error message when I try to start the apps. Didn't work on boot, so I downloaded JDK 1.8.0_40, still no dice. It's looking in the proper location, the file exists and it's using the correct java version. Not sure what the issue is, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the IDE 64 bit? It needs to be the same as the JDK.

Comment: Just testing and Eclipse 4.4 Luna 64 bit runs fine on Yosemite with JDK 1.8

Comment: Not sure how to check to be honest, I did try re-installing Aptana. As far as I can tell they aren't giving me an option for 32 or 64. Aptana uses Eclipse 4.3 as a base. I'll try installing latest eclipse stand alone and see if I get the same error.

--Update
Yep - you're right, Eclipse 4.4 64 bit runs fine for me as well. Maybe I'll just have to wait for an update from these other IDE's.

Comment: Fixed it by downloading this..

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Comment: Weird that this problem arises in both windows and mac and linux never faces this problem.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Download the newest version of Java for OS X 2014-001 from Apple. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

I encountered the same error this morning and this was a quick and easy fix.

Comment: Yep, this is what I did as well. I mentioned in the comments to my question.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm still missing my `/System/Library/Framework/JavaVM.framework/Headers` directory. Any update on what the problem might be?

Comment: yup this worked for me for Zend Studio 10 after installing the yosemite

Comment: Worked for me as well, but I am wondering, why do I have to download Apple's version of Java? I already had a few JDKs installed.

Comment: it worked like a charm, in 5s it was fixed. For 1 min I though that I had screwed  my java

Comment: It looks like this is the legacy version, not the latest version

Answer (score 13):

I got this problem when I try to lunch AptanaStudio 3.1 on OSX yosemite. 
I google this problem for quite a lot and found that JDK1.8(64-bit) version just does not support the Aptana Studio(3.1), maybe also not working on some other IDE which based on the same skeleton of Eclipse.

The only solution I can came out is to install an older version of JDK, and I found that the link @ChancePance provide just worked for me.

Why I am answering this question is just to specify that it's OK to install this version of JDK(which is version 1.6.0_65, 64-bit when I download the package) alongside with the J2SE 1.8(provided by Oracle). So you don't have to worry about there is any conflicts while installing two version of JDK.

I need the JDK1.8 for some of the new features of the latest version of Oracle's J2SE. And I need Aptana Studio at the same time. I am quite worried about there might be some conflicts.

Below is what I have done on OSX Yosemite to solve the problem of AptanaStudio3.1:

1. Download and install the package: [JavaForOSX](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).
2. Found the file "AptanaStidio3.ini", the file by default located under the the directory here: `/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/AptanaStudio3.app/Contents/MacOS`
3. Add "-vm" argument to specify the java which will be used to lunch Aptana Studio. 
   `-vm
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

Hope this will help you guys who got the same problem.

Comment: Thank you. This works like a charm. I did not want to create another instance of eclipse and add as a plug-in. This method of installing 1.6 version of JDK for use with Aptana is simple.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this problem as well. Apparently Aptana Studio is 32-bit, while the java I have installed is 64-bit.

I didn't want to revert to Java6 as the accepted answer suggested, so I solved it another way.

I downloaded a 64-bit version of Eclipse and installed the plugin version of Aptana Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing this problem because I had a 64 bit JDK 1.7 installed (the standard Oracle version - not the Apple version indicated in the other answers) and had mistakenly downloaded a 32 bit version of Eclipse. Doh!!

I removed the 32 bit version and downloaded the 64 bit version of Eclipse and everything works great now.

Answer (score 1):

Simply downloading the newest Java for OSX worked the charm. I clicked and downloaded the file from the link above -> http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US <

Answer (score -1):

Open "/Applications/BonitaBPMCommunity-6.5.0/BonitaBPMCommunity.app/Contents/MacOS/BonitaBPMCommunity.ini"

Obtain the location of the JRE / JDK on your system by executing in a terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
Add 2 lines after adapting the ...jdk1.8.0... to your system as found out above

-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
in between the following lines:

-clearPersistedState
-vmargs
```