# Eclipse won't start since update to yosemite

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-yosemite

My eclipse doesn't start ever since I updated my mac to Yosemite.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOPjH.png)

Any advices?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX Yosemite - JVM Shared library does not contain the JNI\_CreateJavaVM symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914757/osx-yosemite-jvm-shared-library-does-not-contain-the-jni-createjavavm-symbol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading and installing Java for OS X 2014-001 from Apple. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

That should fix your problem.