# Aptana Studio 3 "...does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol" Error

Tags: java, macos, aptana3

I am running Sierra and tried to install and run Aptana 3 however I always get this error message :

> The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
>   does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

Obviously some Java file is missing even though I just installed the latest version of both jdk and jre. I already did reinstall but it didn't change anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914757/osx-yosemite-jvm-shared-library-does-not-contain-the-jni-createjavavm-symbol

Answer (score 2):

this error has very simple solution.
follow link is helpful to you.
just install java for OSX.

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US